# How to change the terminal font when open inside of RubyMine?

Tags: terminal, font-size, rubymine

I am wondering if there is a way for me to change the font size of the terminal when opened inside of RubyMine. I've already checked the terminal setting in RubyMine. The path is set to use zsh as my iTerm terminal.

> Shell path: /bin/zsh

However, the font size is much smaller than the one that I set for iTerm. I've been looking for the solution for a while, but haven't figured it out. I would appreciate it if anybody gives me a hand here.

Answer (score 4):

UI seems to have changed, I use RubyMine 2018.1 on Linux:

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Console Font

Change it and close your open Terminals.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

editor>colors & fonts>console font

then, close and reopen console.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, that is how you change the font of the console inside of rubymine. What I am asking is how to change the font of the TERMINAL inside of Rubymine. :)

Comment: That helped. Thanks!